# Windows 8.1 audio not playing in background

Tags: windows-8.1, background-audio

I'm developing the app that plays music in foreground and background in Windows 8.1. I have done all as per msdn article: [How to play audio in the background](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj841209.aspx)

- declared background audio task
- added `MediaElement` to the page with `AudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia"`
- subscribed to `SystemMediaTransportControls` events

Audio starts playing, but when I press `Start` button, audio pauses until I reopen the app

I have tried msdn sample, but it also stops playing when I press `Start` button - [Stream Online Audio and Play in Background Windows 8.1](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Stream-Online-Audio-and-e4fb5ea1)